# How to prevent a regex looping a url rewrite

Tags: regex, wordpress, infinite-loop, redirect

I'm trying to use the wordpress plugin [Redirection](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) to redirect a url like:

http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg
to

http://mysite.com/subdir/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg

I'm trying `/(wp-content/uploads/.*)` and finding that it redirects to:

http://mysite.com/subdir/subdir/subdir/subdir/subdir/subdir....

and throws an error in Firefox: 'Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.'

I've also tried:

```
^https?://(|www\.)mysite.com.au/(wp-content/uploads/.*)
```

but it seems that redirection doesn't work with the domain - the page loads with a 404, and the URL is not altered.

Any clues appreciated!

Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the rule to ^/wp-content..

additionally, I think the rule was actually interacting with another rule, which seems to be solved by moving my rule to run first, although there's nowhere to specify [L]

In future, when i've kept an eye on the logs to see if I'm getting it right, I'll move the redirects into .htaccess and use the [L] flag @jason suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `[L]` flag for your rewrite to ensure it's the *last*. Otherwise, it keeps rewriting your URL, appending `subdir` every time.

I am not familiar with the Redirection plugin. See if it has this option. If not, I'd suggest a more specific regex or dropping the plugin and writing these yourself, directly in `.htaccess`.

Comment: great tip!  i've read that this is how wordpress manages its default redirects... my rule seems to work if the rule is ^/wp-content.. additionally, I think the rule was actually interacting with another rule, which seems to be solved by moving my rule to run first, although there's nowhere to specify [L]
I guess I should wait a day and make my comment an answer?

Comment: If that's what solved the problem. Internal WP Redirects are complicated. As you noted, sometimes moving the rules around solves the problem. Personally, if it's a site-wide redirect, I do it in `.htaccess`.